# Laravel eloquent issue: Method does not exist

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have 2 tables, Clients and Companies
each Company has many clients and each client has one company

this is my models:

```
class Client extends Model
{
    public function company(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Company');
    }
}

class Company extends Model
{
    public function clients(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Client');
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get a list of all the clients of a company
and this is what I tried to do:

```
$clients = Company::where('guid',$guid)->clients()->all();
```

I'm getting this error:

```
BadMethodCallException in Macroable.php line 74:
Method clients does not exist.
```

thank you for your help!

Comment: `where` will just create a query. Do `Company::where('guid',$guid)->first()->clients()->all()`

Comment: now I'm getting this error now: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::all()

Comment: Maybe: `Company::where('guid',$guid)->first()->clients()->get()`?

Comment: now it's working - thank you! can you please explain me what is the differents between ->get() and ->all() ?

Comment: I think all is just a shortcut on the `Model` to get all model instances. However `clients` is a relationship and not a model so I guess it doesn't work on that. A relationship does however resolve to a query builder when used as a function and the query builder has things like `get` or `first` to execute the query.

Comment: Thanks @aoijryfos, as obvious as it may seem, your comment shed light on why I was getting breakage using `select` after `get()`, using the latter turned it into a `Collection`, when i needed the `Builder`.  After removing `get()` I was able to use the `Builder` as I needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$clients = Company::where('guid',$guid);
```

This returns the Builder class, so when you then add `->clients()` it will give you error because the builder class does not have the clients method, your model does.

The correct code would be..

```
$clients = Company::with('clients')->where('guid',$guid)->get();
```

PS. Don't use `->all()` unless it's something like `$companies = Company::all()`

Answer (score 0):

Your relationship defined at the model must be called like this:

```
$clients = Company::where('guid',$guid)->clients;
```

It will query all clients at your company, don't use the method all() to do this. And on your Client model do the same to search by the company.

```
$company = Client::where('id', 1)->company;
```